# smtp response HELO error checked anything i can

Tags: c#, azure, smtp, smtpclient

below is the code

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("test@myDomain.com", "display name");
message.To.Add(email);

message.Body = "somebody please kill the developer";
message.Subject = subject;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.myDomain.com");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@myDomain.com","myPassword");

client.EnableSsl = False;
client.Port = port;
client.Send(message);
```

- 1st test in my local network - success
- 2nd test application run at
  azure server ~ application setting the same as 1st test - Got HELO error

ping and telnet from azure server is working, already double check the ip and port

[image]

Regards

Just a mediocore developer

Comment: Please post exact error message

Comment: there you go

the error message is the same as catch exception message

thx

Comment: I think you do not have access to your email server.

Comment: The mail server probably requires that **mail.MyDomain.com** (`(new SmtpClient("mail.myDomain.com");`) resolves to your server's IP address.

Comment: yeah, my laptop access was blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your username & password is not authenticating successfully with your SMTP server. Please check it again.